# How to read Oracle Database XML column queried with Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, oracle, express, node-oracledb

I need to read the value that will bring my query to the database in Oracle, I use oracle DB and node.js. the oracle DB returns these values in the column that has XML, but the other columns that has normal values return ok.

```
{
  "tramaenv": {
    "_readableState": {
      "objectMode": false,
      "highWaterMark": 16384,
      "buffer": {
        "head": null,
        "tail": null,
        "length": 0
      },
      "length": 0,
      "pipes": null,
      "pipesCount": 0,
      "flowing": null,
      "ended": false,
      "endEmitted": false,
      "reading": false,
      "sync": true,
      "needReadable": false,
      "emittedReadable": false,
      "readableListening": false,
      "resumeScheduled": false,
      "emitClose": true,
      "autoDestroy": false,
      "destroyed": false,
      "defaultEncoding": "utf8",
      "awaitDrain": 0,
      "readingMore": false,
      "decoder": null,
      "encoding": null
    },
    "readable": true,
    "_events": {},
    "_eventsCount": 1,
    "_writableState": {
      "corkedRequestsFree": {
        "next": null,
        "entry": null
      }
    },
    "writable": true,
    "allowHalfOpen": true,
    "offset": 1
  }
}
```

but the real content is this XML

```
<soapenv:Envelope >
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <imp:obtNroConstanciaElectronica>
            <reqObtNroConstanciaElectronica>
                <idecotizacion>12668264</idecotizacion>
                <ideprod>2003</ideprod>
            </reqObtNroConstanciaElectronica>
        </imp:obtNroConstanciaElectronica>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [MRE] with the node.js code you are using; whether you have any URI for the namespaces (`soapenv` and `imp`) in the XML; and what your expected output is.

Answer (score 0):

If your sample data is:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( id, xml ) AS
SELECT 1, '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="https://example.com/soapenv" xmlns:imp="https://example.com/imp">
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <imp:obtNroConstanciaElectronica>
            <reqObtNroConstanciaElectronica>
                <idecotizacion>12668264</idecotizacion>
                <ideprod>2003</ideprod>
            </reqObtNroConstanciaElectronica>
        </imp:obtNroConstanciaElectronica>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>' FROM DUAL;
```

*(Note: that the namespaces for `soapenv` and `imp` are declared in the XML.)*

Then you can use the SQL query:

```sql
SELECT id,
       x.*
FROM   table_name t
       CROSS APPLY XMLTABLE(
         XMLNAMESPACES(
           'https://example.com/soapenv' AS "soapenv",
           'https://example.com/imp' AS "imp"
         ),
         '/soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/imp:obtNroConstanciaElectronica/reqObtNroConstanciaElectronica'
         PASSING XMLTYPE( t.xml )
         COLUMNS
           idecotizacion NUMBER PATH './idecotizacion',
           ideprod NUMBER PATH './ideprod'
       ) x
```

And the output is:

> | ID | IDECOTIZACION | IDEPROD |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | 12668264 | 2003 |

Then you just need to call that query as you would any other SQL query in your node.js script and get the values.

Comment: All the C based Oracle APIs limit the length of XML strings, so a to_clob() is needed for almost every scenario (unless the XML is known to be short)

Comment: @ChristopherJones The point of this answer is not to return the entire XML but to parse it in the database and return the fields that are required. You can see by the output that the return values are short.

Answer (score 0):

The node-oracledb documentation has a [whole section on XMLType](https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#xmltype).

It appears that you have successfully fetched as CLOB (which is necessary to avoid the XML length being limited to the maxium VARCHAR2 length), ie. you've done something like:

```
const sql = `SELECT XMLTYPE.GETCLOBVAL(res) FROM resource_view`;
```

You can either [stream the LOB](https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/blob/master/examples/lobstream2.js), or tell node-oracledb to [return it directly as a string](https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/blob/master/examples/lobselect.js).  To do the latter, add this to the top of your script:

```
oracledb.fetchAsString = [ oracledb.CLOB ];
```

You should benchmark both solutions and use what's best.

Comment: thank you, I use the first option, and works fine.